# How can I access the flask application configuration outside of the application?

Tags: python, web, flask

I'm not sure if this is a flask specific issue or if I simply lack an understanding of the python import mechanism, but I'm having some problems with a flask web application. Here's the layout of my application:

```
/myapp
  /INSTALL
  /TODO
  /run.py
  /instance
    /application.cfg
  /myapp
    /static
    /templates
    /__init__.py
    /config.py
    /service.py
```

The config.py file stores the default application configuration, and application.cfg stores instance configuration. They both look like this:

```
DEBUG = False
TESTING = False
SECRET_KEY = "please_replace_me"
```

This is how I set up the application in **init**.py:

```
import flask
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_object("myapp.config")
app.config.from_pyfyle("application.cfg", silent=True)
```

Now what I want is to access the app.config object from service.py, which is not included by **init**.py or any of the other modules that are part of the web application. I.e. this is how I want my service.py file to read:

```
from somewhere.somehow import app

def run():
  do_stuff(app.config["CONFIG_OPTION"])
```

The problem is the service.py file has to be inside the package, so I can't move it one folder up and just import myapp. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import the module which is located in the parent directory, one possible way to do it is to add the parent directory to sys.path before importing:

```
cmd_folder = os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe() ))[0])
sys.path.append(cmd_folder+'/../')
```

Comment: I knew this was possible, I guess I was just hoping for a neater solution. I guess I could move some code from __init__.py into a new file (perhaps "app.py") and only import that.

Comment: Suppose the application package will be installed with setuptools, then does the user have to package the instance file as part of the setuptools config?

Answer (score 0):

Python relative imports are relative to `__main__`.

If I assume correctly your `run.py` is the `__main__`. In that case you should be able to do:

```
from myapp import app
```

Comment: Right, but now I want to import app in the service.py file. Actually, run.py runs the debug server, and it's only there to save typing when debugging the application. Like I said, the problem is service.py is inside the myapp folder, and I would prefer to keep it there.

Comment: And is service.py the `__main__`? how do you run your service?

Comment: No, the only __main__ is in run.py. It imports myapp.app (where app is a variable created in the __init__.py) and then calls app.run().

Comment: if run.py is __main__ you should be able to import app, exactly as I posted from any file including service.py.

Comment: Kugel: I've tried that and it doesn't work. Could it be that my package isn't in the python path and so myapp isn't found? Otherwise, perhaps I really am doing something wrong.

Comment: Suppose the application package will be installed with setuptools, then does the user have to package the instance file as part of the setuptools config?